# How to upload images to firebase storage and wait for URLs to return before continuing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to create a "Create Post" form where the user can input text, as well as input images.

```js
uploadImages() {
    const files = document.querySelector('#imagesInput').files;
    files.forEach(image => {
        console.log("uploading", image.name)
        const name = (+new Date()) + '-' + image.name;
        const task = fb.storage.child(name).put(image, {contentType: image.type});
        task.then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                console.log(url);
            })
        })
    });
}
```

The image upload process needs to happen first, and I need to return all the URLs (as an array) before the post is created in the database.

```js
imageURLs = this.uploadImages(); // <-- Wait for this to complete and return the image URIs
this.createPost("Hello, world!", imageURLs) // <-- then do this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call the asynchronous `getDownloadURL()` method a variable number of times (i.e. unknown at the time of coding), you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
uploadImages() {
    const files = document.querySelector('#imagesInput').files;

    const promises = [];
    files.forEach(image => {
        console.log("uploading", image.name)
        const name = (+new Date()) + '-' + image.name;
        const task = fb.storage.child(name).put(image, { contentType: image.type });
        promises.push(task);
    });

    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(snapshotsArray => {
            // snapshotsArray is an array with a variable number of elements
            // You again need to use Promise.all
            const promises = [];
            snapshotsArray.forEach(snapshot => {
                promises.push(snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
            })
            return Promise.all(promises);
        });
}
```

The `uploadImages()` function **is asynchronous** and returns a Promise (since `Promise.all()` and [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) return Promises): you therefore need to call it by using `then()`, as follows:

```
this.uploadImages()
.then(imageURLs => {
   this.createPost("Hello, world!", imageURLs) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `.addOnSuccessListener` to the line where you upload images and add the next part of the code in that

Like this

```
imageURLs = this.uploadImages().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() 
({

this.createPost("Hello, world!", imageURLs)

});
```

I am not sure if the code is entirely correct, it will depend on what you are exactly trying to do, but it will give you a general idea of what you need to do

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, however, the 2nd answer went into more detail. But thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries ! Happy to help ! @Ari